# Site appears very small (almost like a thumbnail) in iPhone

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, html, mobile

[Here is the site.](http://daxdesign.com)

On iPhones, the site comes up very tiny.

[image]

The code I'm using in the header is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure this is solution, but documentation for safari says use `initial-scale=1.0` not `initial-scale=1`. I Googled this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW26

Comment: @StevePerry I figured I might as well give it a shot. I added the `.0` but it's still the same.

Comment: This probably has more to do with your HTML structure and CSS than with the meta tag. Without seeing any of that, I'd suggest you start building from a clean slate and see where it starts to go wrong. Chrome has a handy developer tool that emulates an iPhone.

Comment: Try adding a minimal-scale=1 and maximum-scale=1 as well after your initial-scale=1 If it is still not working then as atheaos said it is probably not the meta-tag.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, that didn't work either. It's strange because it was working fine for months until very recently and nothing was changed. Thanks for your help.